# Get value from dynamic form field before postback with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, sum

I have a form set up, with dynamic fields that get added only if they're needed by the user.

I need to be able to validate the fields (if they're there), before postback in jquery.  The fields are integers and what I really want to do is add the sum of the dynamic fields to make sure they're greater than x figure.

But As far as I can work out, I can't get the value of the field because its not in the DOM yet.

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnHalsey/yq1uhc23/) to demonstrate the problem.  I want to add up the values on an onblur event, it can't be on click of the main submit button unfortunately.

Here is some of the code

```
$(document).on('blur', '.rent-percent', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        console.log(this);
        var value = $('#' + id).val()
        $('#total').append(value * count);

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one and make sure you're not using outdated version of jQuery:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.rent-percent', function () {
    if(!$.isNumeric($(this).val())){
        $(this).val('');
        return alert('Not a Number!');
    }
    var c = 0;
    $('.rent-percent').each(function(){
          c += parseInt($(this).val());                       
    });
    $('#total').html('<h3>Total</h3>'+c);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/yq1uhc23/5/)

Comment: OK, this is a lot closer than I've managed to get, thank you.  How would I get the total div to add up all the values entered in the individual fields?

Comment: Updated my answer and JSFiddle

Comment: Yes as it happens I came up with something similar.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is the id values you're generating have square bracket characters in them.  The HTML4 spec only allows letters, numbers, hyphens, and underscores.  in my experience, jQuery has problems with ids that don't conform to that.  Try fixing the id values and see if that allows you to see the values of the fields.  They ARE in the DOM since they're part of the page.